# Unable to show UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uialertview

in my app i am using validation keys to download content from a server using Wi-Fi. I need to show a UIAlert if the licence keys are wrong or if the wi-fi is not available. I have written the coed for displaying the alert view but the alert is not being displayed... This is scking the blood out my head... Can anyone help please....the control is going over this line, but still the alert is not being displayed.

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString *documentsDirectory=   [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] applicationDocumentsDirectory];   //[pathToStore objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"packages"];

NSString *packagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", path,isbnTemp];

[recievedData writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.zip"] atomically:YES];
NSString *zipPath=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.zip"];

[fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];

    ZipArchive *zipArchive = [[ZipArchive alloc]init];

if([zipArchive UnzipOpenFile:zipPath]){

    if([zipArchive UnzipFileTo:packagePath overWrite:YES]){

        [self loadContent];


    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Unable to UnArchieve the packages");
    }


}
else  {


    NSLog(@"Failure To Open Archive");
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Your ISBN and/or Licence Key are incorrect" message:Nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];    
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried with a not nil message ?

Comment: yes, i have tried it but still i am out of luck....

Comment: the log is being displayed. i tried to print the alert description with a NSLog and it showed the  description. But, the alertView is not being disaplyed

Comment: Add a breakpoint at the line `[alert show];` and check the *alert value. The value must be different of 0x0

Comment: i checked it just now malinois... the value i'v got is 0x65930cO...

Comment: PLEASE SEE MY UPDATED QUESTION MALINOS... i have put the entire method on the question

Comment: The code doesn't help me more, but you can try to declare the alert with a property in the .h file.

Comment: oohk malinos.. thanku so much for ur help.... i will try it out myself...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you trying to show the UIAlertView in a method that is being called from a thread other than the main thread? For example, if you are trying to show the UIAlertView in an asynchronous callback, it could be running on a separate thread.

If so, you need to move the code that shows the UIAlertView to a separate selector, and call it on the main thread using one of the `performSelectorOnMainThread:` methods.

For example, add the following method to your class:

```
-(void)showAlert {
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Your ISBN and/or Licence Key are incorrect" message:Nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

And then change the last else clause in your current code so that it uses:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAlert) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

See the [NSObject class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information on the `performSelectorOnMainThread:` methods.

Comment: PLEASE SEE MY UPDATED QUESTION greg... i have put the entire method on the question

Comment: Your updated code still is not using performSelectorOnMainThread to show the alert view.

Comment: hi greg... i have resolved the issue and my code is now working.. Thanku so much.....

Comment: @AforAlpha what was your solution?

Answer (score 0):

After you've created the alert could you check for a NULL pointer in the alert variable?
Maybe you need to specify a message? Other than that I can't see anything wrong with the code you've posted.

Comment: i could not understand this point james... i mean can you please tell me what is meant by checking for the NULL pointer in the alert variable? are u talking about the nil value i'm passing to the message column??

Comment: He means set a breakpoint after the line that creates the alert, when it's reached put your mouse over the alert variable and see if it points to nil. If you don't know how to work with breakpoints check it programatically with NSLog(alert ? @"not nil" : @"nil");

Comment: ooh:-)... i'v done it zaky.... itz not nil.. the value for the alert is 0x65930cO..... any clues??

Comment: PLEASE SEE MY UPDATED QUESTION zaky and james... i have put the entire method on the question

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant "nil" not "NULL" (I've been using C++ lately lol)!